# wpf touch desktop app in windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, touch, windows-8.1

I have a wpf application that I wrote in windows 7 and worked perfectly.  I am porting over to windows 8.1 and the touch events act totally different.

I have written a control that will switch positions when dragged and dropped onto the another of the same type control.  Below is the previewTouchDown and Drop handlers of the control.

```
private void UserControl_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this, _comparisonElement, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }

private void UserControl_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        ComparisonCopy from = (ComparisonCopy)e.Data.GetData("comparisonFormat");
        ComparisonCopy to = (ComparisonCopy)_comparisonElement.GetData("comparisonFormat");

        if (from != to)
        {
            ComparisonEventArgs args = new ComparisonEventArgs();
            args.from = from;
            args.to = to;

            this.ComparisonMoved(sender, args);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Running this in windows 8.1 causes the drag and drop to work once.  Once it works it will never work again.  It seems like the initial drag/drop is in a stuck state.

I've tried using the DragMove event which will allow the switching multiple times, however, it will randomly switch the controls around.  As soon as I touch another control on the screen it will replace the last control with that one.  Again, seems like the touching is stuck somehow.

Doing this with the mouse works 100% of the time.

Thanks for your help.
-Matt

Answer (score 2):

I used the code example from this post [Drag-and-Drop with Touch on Windows 7](http://wpf.2000things.com/2012/12/21/717-drag-and-drop-with-touch-on-windows-7/) with Windows 8.1 and am seeing something similar.

The Drop event will not fire at all until changing the code to handle TouchMove instead of TouchDown. What I end up with is the following :

```
<StackPanel>
    <Label Content="StackOverflow" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           TouchMove="Label_TouchMove" />
    <Label Content="Drag to here"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           AllowDrop="True" Drop="Label_Drop" />
</StackPanel>

// Drag source
private void Label_TouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    Label l = e.Source as Label;
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(l, l.Content + " was Dragged!", DragDropEffects.Copy);
}

// Drag target
private void Label_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string draggedText = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
    Label l = e.Source as Label;
    l.Content = draggedText;
}
```

But now an extra TouchMove is fired after the drag is completed. I can find no reason for this to happen.